# css - z-index : list with hidden box

Tags: css, list, z-index

I have a list where every element has a share button, when I press on the 
share button a box/bubble opens up with the social mdia buttons.
when the share box opens it should go over the list items (even if it covers the next elements on the list), how can I achieve that?
[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvECc.png)

The box shouldn't push the height of the item list it should be on top of everything

Comment: Sounds like you need `position:absolute`. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: It's too complicated to give a code sample but it looks like that:
`<ul>
   <li>
   <span>TXT</span>
   <button class="share">
     //share popup box
  </button>
</li>
<li>*same here* </li>
<li>*same here* </li>`